# Sending data via ajax gives null value in Post method

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, handler

I am trying to use ajax to send data on my .net Core Razor Page Model with Ajax

This is my Razor Page Code:

```
    $(function () {
        $('#placeRequest').on('click', function () {
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Index?handler=PlaceRequest",
                data: $('#select').val(),
                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                success: function () {
                    alert('Posted using jQuery')
                }
            });
        });
    });


<form method="post">
    <select id="select" class="form-control"></select>

      <div class="form-group button-position col-md4">
          <input type="submit" id="placeRequest" name="placeRequest" value="Place Request" asp-page-handler="PlaceRequest" class="btn btn-primary" />
      </div>
</form>
```

In my Page Model

```
public IActionResult OnPostPlaceRequest(string myData)
{
   //here myData is null
}
```

The problem is that myData in my Post function is null. Am I missing something in the ajax script function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data:{myData:$('#select').val()},
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but myData is still null

Comment: check console.log($('#select').val())  - select - bad variable name for html data

Comment: It prints nothing so I guess the problem is that the value that I am selecting from the dropdown is not taken. I have to mention that the values on the dropdown are coming from on OnGet() function as a JsonResult also with ajax. Could that be a problem?

Comment: No, check select option value   (use Browser- right click - Inspect element)

Comment: or use console.log($('#select option:selected').text());

Answer (score 1):

I found that your last case.I think the problem is your drop-down list doesn't has value.`$('#select').val()` is gets the `value` of the drop-down list.

In your last case,`Asp-for` binds the value of the drop-down list, your select value is null, so the time is null. You should change your code as follows.

```
$("#select").append("<option value='" + item.hour + "'>"  + "'>" + item.hour + "</option>");
```

Then the code:

```
 <select id="select" asp-for="Time" class="form-control"></select>
```

will successfully bind the `Time`.

If you want ajax to submit the value,you just need to change code like @Shaybakov.